# Confidentially seperating web content under single IP address

Tags: http, webserver, confidentiality, vps

I am interested in exposing web content to strangers on the internet (Reddit, Discord, ..).
This content I wish to reside on the same web server under which personal web content resides.

(None of this content yet exists, and I'm not set on a specific web server or programming language.)

VPS (with single IP Address and two domains)

- Content for strangers on the internet (1 domain)
- Job specific services, portfolio, private family services (other domain)

My main worry is that people in real life discover my reddit / discord business.
Equally as worrying is the idea that strangers on reddit / discord can "dox" me.

I could just order an additional IP address from the VPS provider, but first I'd like to explore cost efficient methods.

For any ideas or input I'd be very grateful.

Comment: If you host both sites under the same IP address, it may be possible to discover one site based on the IP address of the other, using tools specifically for this purpose (see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92460/how-can-i-find-out-what-other-websites-are-hosted-from-my-website-ip-address-and).  To avoid this, you may want to consider hosting each site on a separate web server.  With VPS's available for under $5.00/month nowadays (see https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing), this might be a cost effective solution.

Comment: Also, you might want to restrict access to your private site.  This can be done easily using HTTP Authentication.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication.

Comment: I'd just put the domains on services like Cloudflare, so unless you expose non-HTTP service to the public, no one except Cloudflare knows your original IP.